# Как убрать обтекание 2 и 4 элемента li

Tags: html, css, ul, li

Как можно убрать обтекание для 2 и 4 элемента li , я знаю что нужно использовать clear , но как это можно сделать если они все в одном классе?

```css
.just{
  display: flex;
  min-height: 850px;
  align-items: center;
}
.inline{
  border: 2px solid rgb(255,0,0);
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 4em;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 23px;
  width: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="just">
  <div class="for-ul">
    <li class="inline">Новости</li>
    <li class="inline">Ураганы</li>
    <li class="inline">Холдинги</li>
    <li class="inline">Увертюра</li>
    <li class="inline">Драпированный</li>
    <li class="inline">Пролиферация</li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Обтекание - float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

обращение к определенным по счету элементам производится через псевдокласс `:nth-child()` где в скобках указывается конкретный порядковый номер или формула, например `:nth-child(3n+2)` обратится к каждому 3-му элементу начиная со 2-го.
Соответственно, вам подойдет вариант такой `.inline:nth-child(2) {clear: both;}` `.inline:nth-child(4) {clear: both;}`

Comment: или соответственно `.inline:nth-child(2n+0){clear: both;}`

Comment: не, вариант (2n+0) работает и на 6й элемент, а нам надо только 2 и 4

Comment: пусть автор вопроса решает, что ему надо, возможно это все не то что он хочет

Comment: если надо в одну строку, то можно считать в обратном порядке: .inline:nth-last-child(2n+3) {clear: both;}